# Floating comparision in linux kernel gives linking error

Tags: c, linux, floating-point, linux-kernel

In linux kernel module i have below code.

```
float temp
temp = some_function();
if(temp < 0.0f) {
printk("error");
}
```

i am cross compiling it for `arm` platform using `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-` tool-chain

i got below error on   this line   `if(temp < 0.0f) {`

> undefined reference to `__aeabi_fcmplt

I am not getting why this happening. Does am i missing any linking in makefile?

Comment: Probably because GCC has to emulate floating point operations for that platform, and those emulation functions are in the GCC runtime library which is not linked when building a kernel?

Comment: i have not added/linked any lib in makefile

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Last I checked floating point was not allowed in the Linux kernel. Since the cpu arch and ABI you're building for does not support hardware floating point, GCC is generating calls to soft-float functions which are not available in the kernel.

Comment: i also searched stuff and find out that its not possible directly in linux kernel. but still some drivers in kernel use float using some other complex methods. but i dont want to go with that so just updated logic part in my module